# jaxb2-maven-plugin add classpath to generated sources

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb

I use the codehaus jaxb-maven-plugin to create java classes from xml schemas:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>xjc</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/my.xsd</source>
                        </sources>                           
                            <packageName>mypackage</packageName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
```

The classes are generated as expected to `target/generated-sources/jaxb`, but this path is not added to the classpath.

So, if I use some of generated classes in other (not generated) classes, maven cannot found it during the compile process.

Any ideas? TIA!

Comment: This should work. The plugin adds the generated classes to the classpath automatically. What Maven command did you use?

Comment: @Tunaki I used the eclipse m2e plugin, but I can reproduce calling `maven clean compile`. Then I got an error because, the generated package/class cannot be found.

Comment: It seems to be a bug: https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin/issues/44

Comment: @Tunaki: I checked it many time and it works and compiles with eclipse, if I added the classpath manually to eclipse.

Comment: Ha, this is during a Maven release? Then, yep, it appears to be a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in the jaxb2-maven-plugin:

https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxb2-maven-plugin/issues/44

Comment: Fixed in release 2.3

Answer (score 0):

I am running MacOS El Capitain, with version 2.2 of the plugin, if you run "mvn clean compile", the sourcepath is generated correctly.
If you subsequently run "mvn compile", then the source path does not include the path to the generated files.

Correct: during first invocation

```
-sourcepath /Users/nastacio/rsawga-rtc/workspace_trunk/ml-common/src/main/java:/Users/nastacio/rsawga-rtc/workspace_trunk/ml-common/target/generated-sources/jaxb:
```

Missing jaxb path:

```
-sourcepath /Users/nastacio/rsawga-rtc/workspace_trunk/ml-common/src/main/java: -s /Users/nastacio/rsawga-rtc/workspace_trunk/ml-common/target/generated-sources/annotations
```

Comment: Have I? It is possible, as I don't fully understand this domain. But it looks like this "answer" is confirming the problem, maybe explaining it in more detail, but doesn't actually provide a solution to it. That's why I classified is as a "me too" answer. Apologies if I'm wrong!